# Query child snapshot of unknown parent firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch child snapshot with childKey of unknown parent without changing Data Structure.

I tried to use `queryOrderByChildId` with `queryEqual(toValue:, childKey:)` But my problem is that the child snapshot is dictionary and I know only the key, not the value.

Is there any way to manipulate the value to be Any value, In order that I'll be able to get the child snapshot.

I know title/id1, id3 and id3's timestamp

data structure :

```
title:
    id1:
         id2:
              id3:
                   timestamp: 101010101
                   visible: true
```

code:

```
ref.child("title").child(id1).queryOrderedByKey().queryEqual(toValue: _, childKey: id3)
   .observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
      print(snapshot)
}
```

output value is null

**EDIT:**

Finally I solved it like that:

```
ref.child("title").child("id1").queryOrdered(byChild: "id3/timestamp").queryEqual(toValue: 101010101).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
       print("id2 is: ", (snapshot.value as? [String: Any])?.keys.first)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Database queries work on the direct child nodes of the location you run the query at. There can be only one unknown key in the entire path: the nodes directly under the node you query.

So if you know the `title/id1` part of the path, you can query the nodes on level `id2` based on their keys, values, or properties at a known path under that (like `date/month`.

If you know `title/id1/id2`, you can query the nodes on the `id3` level. But you can't query those, if you only know the `title/id1` part of their path.

Also see:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Ok thanks, Let's supposed that I know title/id1, id3 and id3's timestamp, How should my query look like in order to get id3 datasnapshot.value? @frank

Comment: As said: there can only be one unknown level in the query. If you only know `title/id1`, you're trying to query `title/id1/*/*/timestamp`, which isn't possible.

Comment: As I mention I know also the **value of id3** and the value of timestamp. Is that helpful ? I know `title/id1/*/id3/timestamp` @frank

Comment: I don't know only the value of id2 @Frank

Comment: If `id3/timestamp` is a fixed path you can create an index under `id1` for it, and query that way. But if `id3` is different for many child nodes, it's a categorization problem. In that case check my answer on the second question I linked. Note that's easier to understand what you're trying and how you can accomplish if you don't make the problem abstract with `id1`, `id2` and `id3`, but show the actual values and their meaning.